# Split a list by half the length and add new column with dependent values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv datafile that I've split by a column value into 5 datasets for each person using:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    PersonData = df[df['Person'] == i].values
    P[i] = PersonData
```

I want to sort the data into ascending order according to one column, then split the data half way at that column to find the median.

So I sorted the data with the following:

```
dataP = {}

for i in range(1,6):
    sortData = P[i][P[i][:,9].argsort()]
    P[i] = sortData
    P[i] = pd.DataFrame(P[i])
dataP[1]
```

Using that I get a dataframe for each of my datasets 1-6 sorted by the relevant column (9), depending on which number I put into dataP[i].

Then I calculate half the length:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    middle = len(dataP[i])/2
    print(middle)
```

Here is where I'm stuck!

I need to create a new column in each dataP[i] dataframe that splits the length in 2 and gives the value 0 if it's in the first half and 1 if it's in the second.

This is what I've tried but I don't understand why it doesn't produce a new list of values 0 and 1 that I can later append to dataP[i]:

```
for n in range(1, (len(dataP[i]))):
    for n, line in enumerate(dataP[i]):
        if middle > n:
            confval = 0
        elif middle < n:
            confval = 1
for i in range(1,6): 
    Confval[i] = confval
Confval[1]
```

Sorry if this is basic, I'm quite new to this so a lot of what I've written might not be the best way to do it/necessary, and sorry also for the long post.

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right I believe you are attempting to do two things.

1. Find the median value of a column
2. Create a new column which is 0 if the value is less than the median or 1 if greater.

Let's tackle #1 first:

`median = df['originalcolumn'].median()`

That easy! There's many great pandas functions for things like this.

Ok so number two:

`df['newcolumn'] = df[df['originalcolumn'] > median].astype(int)`

What we're doing here is creating a new bool series, false if the value at that location is less than the median, true otherwise. Then we can cast that to an int which gives us 0s and 1s.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I was trying to split by half the length and not the median is to control for if any values get lost by being equal to the median value. Would your solution account for that?

As for part 2, that's exactly what I'm trying to do but I think because I'm separating my data into different people using the function dataP[ i ] I don't know how to write the new column - would it be dataP[ i, 'new column']? I wonder if I should create temporary csv files for each person's data and work with those, in which case I think what you're saying would work?

Comment: @Jess123456 The way I wrote it, it will mark any values equal to the median as 0s. If you want to mark them as 1s, simply change the `>` to a `>=`.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to mark half of them as 0s and the other half as 1s so that if there are a few they will be equally split between the two groups?